# WEB API session handling between 2 methods POST and GET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to Save the model data in `HttpContext.Current.Session["TestModel"]` in on the `POST` method and trying to retrieve the same model data from `HttpContext.Current.Session["TestModel"]` in `GET` method. Below is the code what I am trying:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadDataJson(HttpRequestMessage request)
{

    var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
    OasisSessionModel oasissessionmodel = new OasisSessionModel(); //I tried setting it as a global
    oasissessionmodel.TotalRows = 200;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["TestModel"] = oasissessionmodel;
    return someresponse;
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/GetUploadUpdates")]
public IHttpActionResult GetUploadUpdates()
{
    var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
    OasisSessionModel oasissessionmodel = null;
    oasissessionmodel = HttpContext.Current.Session["TestModel"] as OasisSessionModel;
    return Ok();
}
```

But in this case `HttpContext.Current.Session["TestModel"]` is always `null`, is there any other way to handle session Globally in WEB API. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx#CodeExamples)

This might be a solution to your problem, are you using .NET to access the API (MVC, etc.)?

Comment: Its a .Net WEBAPI and i have added protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
} in global.asax , but still it doent work